# Vite creating its own node_modules in workspace instead of using monorepo

Tags: javascript, npm, vite, monorepo, react-fullstack

I have a monorepo for a fullstack webapp with the following directory structure

```
.
├── client
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── src
│   └── vite.config.ts
├── node_modules
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── server
│   ├── package.json
│   └── src
├── tsconfig.json
└── tsconfig.node.json
```

However, when I run `npm run dev -ws client`, vite generates it's own `node_modules/` inside `client/`.

```
.
├── client
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── node_modules <--- this
│   │   └── .vite
│   │       └── deps_temp
│   │           └── package.json
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── src
│   └── vite.config.ts
```

My understanding is that the point of using npm workspaces is to avoid having multiple `node_modules/` in each sub-project, instead having all dependencies installed in the root `node_modules/`. Vite generating its own seems to defeat that point.

I'm assuming I don't have something configured properly (I used `npx create-vite` to setup vite).

Output of `npm run dev -ws client`

```
> @sargon-dashboard/client@0.0.0 dev
> vite client

(!) Could not auto-determine entry point from rollupOptions or html files and there are no explicit optimizeDeps.include patterns. Skipping dependency pre-bundling.

  VITE v3.2.4  ready in 175 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
```

Contents of `vite.config.ts`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()]
})
```

contents of `root/package.json`

```json
{
    "name": "app",
    "private": true,
    "workspaces": [
        "client",
        "server"
    ]
}
```

contents of `root/client/package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "@app/client",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.8",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4",
    "vite": "^3.2.3"
  }
}
```

contents of `root/server/package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "@app/server",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did nothing wrong. `node_modules/.vite` is the default vite cache directory. It only looks like a misconfiguration in a monorepo because you don't expect a node_modules folder inside the packages anymore.

If you want, you can configure a different path:
https://v2.vitejs.dev/config/#cachedir